# Parallel Posts to test Rails API performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, jenkins, parallel-processing

I need to test my Rails API's performance.

To do so, I created a few Cucumber features that allow me to test singular and bulk post request to the API in sequence with a generic `@child` that inserted `number_of_times` times. Something like:

```
if insertion == 'bulk'
  Parent.all.each do | test_run |
    number_of_times.times { |i| children << parent.child.new(@child) }
  end
  Child.import children
elsif insertion == 'realtime'
  Parent.all.each do | test_run |
    number_of_times.times { |i| parent.child.create!(@child) }
end
```

Now what I need to do, is to insert for example 1000, but divide it by 5 parallel requests. Something like the code below sent 5 times in parallel. My database will be inserting 5 `children` at the same time, 200 times on each "thread".

```
200.times { |i| parent.child.create!(@child) }
```

Is this possible to be done? Preferably using cucumber (or similar) so I can run it in Jenkins as CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you're asking:

```
num_threads = 5
num_times = 200
threadpool = []

num_threads.times do
  # create a thread to do parallel work in, save the thread to the pool
  threadpool << Thread.new do
    # do the actual work
    Parent.find_each do |parent|
      num_times.times { |i| parent.child.create!(@child) }
    end
  end
end

# call join on each thread to wait for them to finish
threadpool.map &:join
```

This uses just plain Ruby so it should work in jenkins.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This does seem to do the trick in creating threads and add then to the threadpool but unfortunately the insertions are not done. I debugged the code and the `threadpool.map &:join` isn't even "processed". Have any clues to why this happens?

Comment: What do you mean by processed? that line will wait for all the threads to finish, which i would assume takes a long time since each of them are doing 200 creates, you just have to give it some time. If you add a puts above the line where you're creating a child, you should see all the threads logging to the terminal

Comment: My problem is another. For some reason I can't read the Parent, your code was correct :). Thanks for the help.